# Using a CSV file to create a stem plot

Tags: r, csv

I'm new to R (and anything programming related) so am getting my head around what is actually happening.

I created a CSV file in Excel with one column consisting of names and the other column consisting of pretend exam scores for each name. I saved it from Excel as a CSV file.

So to import it into R I used the following command:

```
data1<- read.csv(file.choose(),header=F)
```

When I created the CSV file I didn't create any headers so the column for names is given the header V1 and the column for the exam scores is given the header V2.

So to create my stem plot I then use the command:

```
class_stem <- stem(data1$V2)
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this?

My real confusion starts when I import the data as a table. Should I be even importing it as a table or just leaving it as I had done? My purpose at this stage was just to create a stem and leaf plot

Comment: This seems fine. Is there a problem you're experiencing?

Comment: there is no difference between `read.csv` and `read.table` except for some default parameters.

Comment: I suggest you read up on concepts such as `data.frame` (`list`) and `matrix` (`array`, `vector`).